# Getting specific Xml node

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, feedparser

How can I get "entry" nodes from this feed

> http://www.google.com/alerts/feeds/14392773026536511983/5526937985735563348

I tried linq to xml but I think because of the existing attributes of entry tags following code does not work.

```
string url = "http://www.google.com/alerts/feeds/14392773026536511983/5526937985735563348";

WebClient c = new WebClient();

string xml = ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetString(c.DownloadData(url));

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var entries = doc.Descendants("entry");
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: There is no XPath expression here. Retagging.

Comment: I've add it if someone will propose a xpath solution in the place of linq to xml. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not specifying a namespace. Try this:

```
XNamespace atom = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
var entries = doc.Descendants(atom + "entry");
```

Btw, I wouldn't use ASCII for this, or `DownloadData`... use `WebClient.DownloadString` to handle the encoding for you. Or indeed, just use `XDocument.Load(url)`:

For example:

```
string url = ...;

XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(url);
XNamespace atom = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
var entries = doc.Descendants(atom + "entry");
Console.WriteLine(entries.Count()); // Prints 20
```

Answer (score 1):

This data presented in Atom format, so you need to parse it according to the standard specification. The simplest way is take a look on to open source code. Check out [This link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/smart/rssfeeder.aspx#GenericParser), you are need "Creating a generic parser for Atom, RDF and RSS feeds" part